# Build an ASP.NET website project in VS 2012 without the .cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, build, build-process

How can i build my ASP.NET website project so that it will be ready to upload to the hosting server without the .cs files.

I can use the Web Publish protocol as it is not available in my hosting company.

Comment: Publish it to your local machine then upload via FTP, there's an option for it in your Publish dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Publish/Deploy to a local folder and then ftp/copy that folder upto your hosting provider

Comment: How can i publish to a local folder ? it requires a server .... do i have to pusblish to my local iis before uploading ?

Comment: No... simply right click Project in VS; create a new publish profile with a publish method of FileSystem. Set the target location to a folder of your choosing. Click publish. The entire contents of that folder are what you will the FTP to your provider